# Why the negative sign on that line?

Tags: integration

First of all, sorry if the question is stupid. I am banging my head to understand that.

As far as I know,

[image]

I am trying to understand the following explanation:

[image]

On that explanation, the guy does exactly this integral but comes with a negative sign for the natural log...

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is $v(t)$, which has a negative sign in the denominator. Use the substitution $u = V - v(t)$.

Also note that
$$\int\frac1x\ dx = \begin{cases}
\ln(-x) + C_1,  & x < 0 \\
\ln x + C_2, & x > 0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I thought I was seeing your answer but not. :(

Comment: got it now. THANKS!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

He doesn't do exactly that integral. Note the sign in front of $v(t)$ in the denominator.

Comment: care to explain?

Comment: @SpaceDog Differentiate $\ln(V-v(t))$ with respect to $v(t)$ (remember the chain rule), and see what you get.

Comment: got it, thanks!